# Game not recognizing Virtual CD

Tags: windows-xp, compact-disc

Some software (Diablo II, as it happens) is complaining that it cannot find the "play CD" in the CD drive (It uses this as a protection mechanism.) I have the play CD virtually mounted with MagicDisk, not in drive D, which is taken by the physical CD drive, but rather in drive F. (Using Windows XP.)

How can I convince the software to see this virtual CD?

Comment: Just to note that the final DII patch removes the cd requirement

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do as an alternative is register the key on your Battle.net account, then you can download a fresh copy that does not require a CD or CD key to play

Comment: Second this!  I Highly recommend doing this as well, since it allows you to have unlimited downloads of your legally registered Blizzard software.  And you can recover your keys if necessary....